# Is it slower when using 3TB hard drives on Windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance

For some reason I have a notion that it's somehow detrimental to the performance of your windows machine (and other OSs?) to use hard drives that are larger than 2TB. When I was thinking about this, I realised that I had no idea why I thought this and if it was true.

So is there any downside to using hard drives larger than 2TB?

Comment: @CharlesH That question doesn't answer the specific question, just if there's a general correlation between size and speed.

Comment: There is no correlation between the speed of a HDD and the size of a HDD.  Where exactly did you learn this notion because its not correct.  Clearly the size of a HDD will determine how long a complete scan of the HDD will take but that's a separate concern.

Comment: Is there an actual problem you are dealing with? What have you researched and found so far?

Comment: Aha, vindication. On looking around further, I've found [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/11/29/enabling-large-disks-and-large-sectors-in-windows-8.aspx) talking about "very large volumes". It at least seems to indicate that there's a difference.

Comment: I see nothing by the author of that article that mentions speed or access time.  What I do find interesting is the graphic is actually 100% accurate.  **8TB disks were announced at the end of 2014 and will be released in the first half of 2015.**